# Do I need to do anything to make a CMake-generated buildsystem compile sources for targets with link dependencies between each other in parallel?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm working on a project with a dependency tree like so:

```
main
|_ libB
   |_ libA
```

Since `libB` depends on headers from `libA`, I'm doing:

```
target_link_libraries(libB PRIVATE libA)
```

But this implies creating a hard dependency between those libs if I understood correctly?

So after that line, CMake will understand that `libA` needs to be built entirely before building `libB`, thus increasing compilation time where it isn't needed.

How could I make `libB` depend on `libA`'s include directories without depending on the full compilation of `libA` at the same time?

PS: This use case is a very simplified version of my actual problem, but it allows me to explain it simply.

Comment: Depends on how you're building the code, ninja for example will parallelise the building of the code from libA and libB and only delay the link of libB until libA is linked

Comment: I'm using MSBuild and I'm not in a position where I could use Ninja instead (I wish I could tho)...

I don't need any kind of dependency between libA and libB, I just need include dirs to be propagated :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that doesn't require using another generator.

I'm stuck using MSBuild to generate a Visual Studio solution (not that I agree with this).

The solution I found is this function I wrote:

```
# Propagates include directories from target_src and its dependencies to target_dst
function(target_propagate_include_dirs target_dst target_root)
    if (${ARGC} LESS 3)
        set(target_src ${target_root})
    else()
        set(target_src ${ARGV2})
    endif()

    # Get dependencies of target
    get_target_property(DEPENDENCIES ${target_src} INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES)

    foreach(MODULE IN LISTS DEPENDENCIES)
        if (TARGET "${MODULE}" AND NOT "${MODULE}" STREQUAL "${target_root}" AND NOT "${MODULE}" STREQUAL "${target_dst}")
            # Get include directories of current module
            get_target_property(INCLUDE_DIRS ${MODULE} INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

            # Propagate those directories into "module_include" target
            foreach(DIR IN LISTS INCLUDE_DIRS)
                target_include_directories(${target_dst} INTERFACE "${DIR}")
            endforeach()

            # Recurse over dependencies
            target_propagate_include_dirs(${target_dst} ${target_root} ${MODULE})
        endif()
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

A more accurate layout of my project is:

```
|_module
  |_ moduleA
  |_ moduleB
  |_ ...
|_source
  |_libs
    |_ libA
    |_ libB
    |_ ...
  |_main
```

Here, I had two INTERFACE libraries, `module` and `libs`, and a `main` executable.

Each lib in `libs` depend on `module`, and `main` depends on `libs`.

The only solution I found was to use my function to propagate the include directories to another INTERFACE target, `module_include` for example:

```
add_library(module_include INTERFACE)

target_propagate_include_dirs(module_include module)
```

That way, I can depend of `module_include` to get the include directories automatically, without depending on the compilation of each module.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use ninja to fix the compilation ordering brought by the dependency, but there are workaround for build systems that are not optimized for that.

The workaround way would be to just add the include directory of the other target:

```
target_include_directories(libB PRIVATE $<TARGET_PROPERTY:libA,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)
```

I would still add a comment that says this is only a workaround for MSBuild lacking.

Answer (score 0):

> So after that line, CMake will understand that libA needs to be built entirely before building libB, thus increasing compilation time where it isn't needed.

Where did you get that idea? How a buildsystem handles dependencies like this is up to the buildsystem- not to CMake. CMake just generates buildsystems. CMake might need to do things to help the buildsystem out in understanding what kind of dependency it is, but generally I don't think that's needed. Just try out various generators. You'll probably observe that the smarter ones compile sources for such targets at the same time. It's only at the linking step that two binaries that link with each other need to be ready for linking.

But for targets with many sources, you might not observe that even with smarter buildsystems just because of the fact that your machine only has so many cores (you can only get so much parallelism), and according to the number of cores your machine has, at a certain point, building the sources of multiple targets in parallel has no speed gains (when your targets have a sufficient number of source files).

> How could I make libB depend on libA's include directories without depending on the full compilation of libA at the same time?

As already stated, for a smart buildsystem, you shouldn't need to do anything special. Let CMake do its job, and let the generated buildsystem do its job.

However, if you want to crutch something, you can directly specify target include dirctories (using `target_include_directories()`) instead of letting CMake do its thing with `target_link_libraries`. But then you'd have to use even more crutches to handle things like linking the targets... Unless there's nothing to link- in which case it's a header-only library with nothing to build, where what you're worrying about is a non-issue...

Answer (score 0):

In Modern CMake (cmake > 3.0) you can create [INTERFACE libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries), ie abstractions that "act like" libraries but are not a real library.

This allows you to do exactly what you need - reference the include files without actually spending time compiling.

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0 )
project(main)

# In your library folder
add_library( test INTERFACE )
target_include_directories( test INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )

# back in the root folder
add_executable( main main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( main test )
```

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/7bea6178Y